# Outlook Add-In Call Existing Ribbon Item

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm currently working on a project for Outlook 2019, where I would like to just have a simple add-in to backup all my email accounts by the press of a button.

Instead of doing the tedious job of clicking:

```
File -> Open & Export -> Import/Export ->Import and Export wizard -> Export to a file -> Outlook Data File(.pst) -> <Select Email accounts> -> <Choose output options> -> Finish
```

This takes quite a while to do especially if you have more than just one email account you want to backup.

I have already created an Outlook VSTO (C#) Add-in project in Microsoft's Visual Studio 2019 and created a Ribbon item which contains a button to perform this task for me.

Only question I have is how can I call the entire operation mentioned above i.e

```
File -> Open & Export -> Import/Export ->Import and Export wizard -> Export to a file -> Outlook Data File(.pst) -> <Select Email accounts> -> <Choose output options> -> Finish
```

inside the `On_Click` operation of my button inside the ribbon I created?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new PST file using Namespace.`AddStore` / `AddStoreEx`, find the new store in the `Namespacce.Stores` connection (you'd think `AddStore` would return the new store, but not).

Find the source store in the `Namespace.Stores` collection, recursively loop through the folders in the  `Store.GetRoodFolder().Folders` collection, for each message in a folder copy it into a target folder (you'd need to create it first using `Folder.Folders.Add`) using `MailItem.Copy` / `MailItem.Nove(TargetFolder)`